# Undefined reference when instantiating a class

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, oop, class

This is my **main.cpp**. Here is where I have the problem:

I get two errors:

*undefined reference to `BankController::BankController(TransactionRepository*)* at line 23

and

*undefined reference to `TransactionFileRepository::TransactionFileRepository(std::string)* at line 19

For both of them, the type is C/C++ Problem, resource is main.cpp

> ```
> #include "bankgui.h"
> #include "Controller/BankController.h"
> #include "Repository/TransactionFileRepository.h"
> #include "Repository/TransactionMemoryRepository.h"
> #include "Repository/TransactionRepository.h"
>
> #include <QtGui>
> #include <QApplication>
> #include <string>
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
>
>   string path = "DataStorage/Database.txt";
>
>   //Instantiate the main data repository
>   TransactionRepository* mainDatabase;
>   mainDatabase = new TransactionFileRepository(path); // <-- Error here
>
>   //Instantiate the main controller
>   BankController* mainController;
>   mainController = new BankController(mainDatabase); // <-- Same Error here
>
>   //Starts the GUI
>   QApplication app(argc, argv);
>   BankGUI* mainWidget;
>   mainWidget = new BankGUI(mainController);
>   mainWidget->show();
>
>   return app.exec();
> }
> ```

I have 3 classes:

- a virtual **TransactionRepository**
- one class that implements the above **TransactionMemoryRepository**
- one class that inherits the above **TransactionMemoryRepository** into **TransactionFileRepository**

The 3 classes' header files are:

**TransactionRepository**

> ```
> #ifndef TRANSACTIONREPOSITORY_H_
> #define TRANSACTIONREPOSITORY_H_
>
> //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> #include "../Domain/BankTransaction.h"
> #include "../Utils/Vector.h"
> #include "../Domain/exceptions.h"
>
> //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> class TransactionRepository {
> public:
>
>   /*
>    *  Search and return the address of a transaction with the matching id
>    */
>   virtual BankTransaction* findById(int id) = 0;
>
>   /*
>    *  Returns the list of transactions
>    */
>   virtual Vector<BankTransaction*>findAll() = 0;
>
>   /*
>    *  Save a bank transaction in the list
>    */
>   virtual void save(BankTransaction) throw (RepositoryException) = 0;
>
>   /*
>    *  Update a transaction
>    *
>    */
>   virtual void update(int id, int day, string type, float amount, string desc) = 0;
>
>   /*
>    *  Removes a transaction from our list
>    */
>   virtual void remove(int id) = 0;
>
>   /*
>    *  Return the total number of transactions from our list
>    */
>   virtual void getNr() = 0;
>
>   /*
>    *  Get a copy of the list
>    */
>   virtual void getCopy(Vector<BankTransaction> list) = 0;
>
>   virtual ~TransactionRepository(){}
>
> };
>
> //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> #endif /* TRANSACTIONREPOSITORY_H_ */
>
> //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

**TransactionMemoryRepository**

> ```
> #ifndef TRANSACTIONMEMORYREPOSITORY_H_
> #define TRANSACTIONMEMORYREPOSITORY_H_
>
> #include "TransactionRepository.h"
> #include "../Utils/Vector.h"
>
> class TransactionMemoryRepository: public TransactionRepository {
> public:
>   TransactionMemoryRepository();
>   virtual ~TransactionMemoryRepository();
>
>   /*
>    *  Search and return the address of a transaction with the matching id
>    */
>   BankTransaction* findById(int id);
>
>   /*
>    *  Returns the list of transactions
>    */
>   Vector<BankTransaction*>findAll();
>
>   /*
>    *  Save a bank transaction in the list
>    */
>   void save(BankTransaction) throw (RepositoryException);
>
>   /*
>    *  Update a transaction
>    *
>    */
>   void update(int id, int day, string type, float amount, string desc);
>
>   /*
>    *  Removes a transaction from our list
>    */
>   void remove(int id);
>
>   /*
>    *  Return the total number of transactions from our list
>    */
>   void getNr();
>
>   /*
>    *  Get a copy of the list
>    */
>   void getCopy(Vector<BankTransaction> list);
>
> protected:
>
>   Vector<BankTransaction*> TransactionList;
>
> };
>
> #endif /* TRANSACTIONMEMORYREPOSITORY_H_ */
> ```

**TransactionFileRepository**

> ```
> #ifndef TRANSACTIONFILEREPOSITORY_H_
> #define TRANSACTIONFILEREPOSITORY_H_
>
> #include <string>
> #include "../Repository/TransactionMemoryRepository.h"
> #include "../Utils/Vector.h"
> #include "../Domain/BankTransaction.h"
>
> using namespace std;
>
> class TransactionFileRepository: public TransactionMemoryRepository {
>
> private:
>   string fileName;
>   Vector<BankTransaction*> loadFromFile();
>   void writeToFile();
>
> public:
>   TransactionFileRepository(string filepath);
>   virtual ~TransactionFileRepository();
>   virtual BankTransaction* findById(string id);
>   virtual Vector<BankTransaction*> findAll();
>   virtual void save(BankTransaction) throw  (RepositoryException);
>   virtual void update(BankTransaction) throw (RepositoryException);
>   virtual void remove(string studentId) throw (RepositoryException);
> };
>
> #endif /* TRANSACTIONFILEREPOSITORY_H_ */
> ```

The .cpp files for the last two classes (since the virtual one doesn't require a .cpp file) don't have much implemented in them. The only thing I added are the protptypes in the (.h)eader files.

I've been searching for two hours on google for solutions but everything I try doesn't get rid of those errors.

I should mention that this is a C++ QT project that I am working on. I had to add to the project properties the include paths for some things to work.

All files that are included exist.

Comment: can you please tell for which variables is the undefined reference?

Comment: What kind of problem do you have? Compilation, linking, runtime?

Comment: edited; check top of post

Comment: Too much code, narrow it down.

Comment: The code of the three classes were added just in case someone needs to see it. 

The code where the problem is is in main.cpp, lines that give out errors have been commented

Comment: so is the constructor `TransactionFileRepository::TransactionFileRepository(std::string)` actually defined somewhere? And are you linking with that?

Comment: It's an empty constructor defined in TransactionFileRepository.cpp. I am using Eclipse IDE and I think the linking is done automatically.

Comment: I've looked all around my project and I can't seem to find the reason why the undefined reference occurs

Comment: @Useless what do you mean by linking with that?

Comment: You can typically compile `main.cpp` to `main.o` without needing the constructor definition. You can also compile `TransactionFileRepository.cpp` to `TransactionFileRepository.o`. It's linking them together to form an executable where this problem arises. You need to find out how eclipse manages this, and if possible see how it's invoking your compiler and/or linker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)